# Force application on Mac to only use Airport connection

Tags: networking, redirection, airport

My MacBook Pro has a physical ethernet connection to the corporate network that uses a HTTP proxy server. I also have an Airport connection to a router that bypasses the proxy server.  My order of network connections must remain corporate first, then Airport.

I have one application that requires the Airport connection but I can't use it unless I change the order of connections which breaks other things. Is there any way to force this application to use the Airport connection?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at adding static routes for Mac OS X. I haven't done this in over 18 months, but there are a couple tutorials I found which may help :)

From [here](http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/):

> #### Simple solution:
>
> ```
> route -n add 10.0.0.0/8 10.16.3.254
> ```
>
> #### Permanent solution:
>
> Add a startup item (to avoid doing the above command every reboot)
>
> ```
> cd /System/Library/StartupItems
> mkdir AddRoutes 
> cd AddRoutes
> ```
>
> Create a file called `AddRoutes` (note: same as the folder name) `vi AddRoutes`
>
> ——————
>       #!/bin/sh
>
> ```
> # Set static routing tables
>
> . /etc/rc.common
>
> StartService () { if [ "${ADDROUTES:=-NO-}" = "-YES-" ]; then
> ConsoleMessage “Adding Static Routing Table” sudo route -nv add
> 10.0.0.0/8 10.16.3.254 fi }
>
> StopService () { return 0 }
>
> StopService () { return 0 }
>
> RestartService () { return 0 }
>
> RunService “$1″
> ```
>
> ——————
>
> Then create a file `StartupParameters.plist`
>   ——————
>
> ```
> {
> Description = “Add static routing tables”;
> Provides = (”AddRoutes”);
> Requires = (”Network”);
> OrderPreference = “None”;
> }
> ```
>
> —————-
>
> Then change permissions:
>
> ```
> chmod 755 AddRoutes StartupParameters.plist
> ```
>
> Reboot your computer. Verify with `netstat -nr`

Comment: This is probably what the user needs.  BUt there is an important point, this only works if the destination address is unique for the airport application.  If it is connecting to the same server as something that needs to go over ethernet, than this won't work.

Comment: I am clueless as to how the route command works. If my router is airport router address is 10.0.1.1 and I am trying to get to 8 10.16.3.254 then I would use route -n add 10.0.0.0/8 10.16.3.254 Is that correct? Sorry to be a dunce. I am new to this. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @KeithB - last I did this, I was routing all 10/24 traffic over eth0, and everything else over my aircard (which had priority for connections on my laptop)